# get selected checkboxs from tableview

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have tableview with checkbox in each row and I have an action button. My problem is that, how can I get selected checkbox from tableview to apply an action when the button is pressed?

This is how I add the checkbox to the tableview

```
    public void addCeckBoxToTableView() {
    /** define a simple boolean cell value for the action column so that the column will only be shown for non-empty rows. */
    tcCb.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Object, Boolean>,
            ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Object, Boolean> p) {
            return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
        }
    });
    /** create a cell value factory with an add button for each row in the table. */
    tcCb.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Object, Boolean>, TableCell<Object, Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Object, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Object, Boolean> p) {
            return new CheckBoxCell();
        }
    });
}

    private class CheckBoxCell extends TableCell<Object, Boolean> {
    CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
    HBox hb = new HBox(checkBox);
    /**
     * places button in the row only if the row is not empty.
     */
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (!empty) {
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
            setGraphic(hb);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

cordially.

Comment: With that setup, you can't. The problems are: 1. you don't set the value of the boolean property when your check box is checked/unchecked, and 2. you don't keep a reference to the boolean property provided to the `cellValueFactory`. Use a standard [`CheckBoxTableCell`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html) and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940563 (or others, just search...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm of the same opinion as James: "with that setup you can't"

But you could do it this way

```
private TableView<Record> table;
private TableColumn<Record, Boolean> tcCb;
private Button actionButton;

public class Record {
    private SimpleBooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
        return selected;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    table = new TableView<Record>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Record(), new Record(), new Record()));
    table.setEditable(true);
    // Create "CheckBox" - Column
    tcCb = new TableColumn<Record, Boolean>("Boolean-Column");
    tcCb.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Record, Boolean>("selected"));
    tcCb.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(tcCb));
    tcCb.setEditable(true);
    table.getColumns().add(tcCb);
    // Create actionButton for retrieving cellData
    actionButton = new Button("action");
    actionButton.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getItems().size(); row++) {
            System.out.println(tcCb.getCellData(row));
        }
    });
    // The uninteresting stuff...
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(table, actionButton)));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UI elements should associate them with the object. In your example, you wanted to apply the action on items which are selected(Selected CheckBox).

The Object associated with the table can be like this

```
public class TableData{
private Boolean selected=Boolean.False;
public void setSelected(Boolean isSelected){
this.isSelected = isSelected;
}

public boolean isSelected(){
return this.selected;
}
}
```

So In TableCell,
When the checkBox is selected, update 'selected' Boolean value of TableData,by adding a selection action listener to the CheckBox.

then you can iterate through the TableData which you can get it from the TableView, to apply the actions upon Button selection.